# Call HTTP func in a function registry

Tags: go

I have a func registry but I don't know how can I call a HTTP func on it.

```
registry := map[string]func(){
    "MyFunc1": MyFunc1,
}
registry["MyFunc1"]()

func MyFunc1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hi Gorilla!"))
}
```

I changed them to these:

```
registry := map[string]func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request){
    "MyFunc1": MyFunc1,
}
```

But I can not call it now!

```
gorilla.HandleFunc("/", registry["MyFunc1"]()).Name(parentKey)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From, the documentation, `HandleFunc` expects a `func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)` type.

However, you have a typo in your code because you are not giving the function as argument, you are calling it:

Change the part `registry["MyFunc1"]()` into `registry["MyFunc1"]`

Comment: Thanks How can I check exists an item like if registry["MyFunc100"] {} without call it

Comment: It's a simple map, so you can check if an entry exists , there are examples in https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action

Comment: non-bool registry["MyFunc100"] (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) used as if condition

Comment: `if fn, ok := registry["Myfunc100"]; ok { fn(resp, req) }`

Comment: I have nothing in http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request type (in call) I just want check an item in that map (just check the key)